# Apex trigger When the customer replied to a case via email then case status changes to Updated

Tags: apex, trigger

I created this code but when a case is created from email its automatically change the status but i want to only update status as updated when customer replies.

```java
trigger UpdateCaseOnEmailReply on EmailMessage (before insert) {
    // get the case IDs from the incoming emails
    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (EmailMessage email : Trigger.new) {
        if (email.Incoming && email.ParentId != null) {
            caseIds.add(email.ParentId);
        }
    }

    // retrieve the cases and update their status to 'Updated'
    List<Case> casesToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds];
    for (Case c : casesToUpdate) {
        c.Status = 'Updated';
    }
    update casesToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: The first thing to do would be to determine if it's a customer reply, or a reply from someone else. What have you researched/tried to make that determination? What criteria would make this a "customer reply". Those are questions that only you can answer right now.

Comment: also, this would be more appropriate as an "after" trigger (you're not making any changes to the triggered records, the `EmailMessage` records). The query on `Case` is also not required because you can set a record Id in the SObject constructor (you can iterate over the ids and `myList.add(new Case(Id = caseId, Status = 'Updated'));`)

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you could give more details on how the Case is created (standard email to case or custom email service ?).
In order to identify update (or emails that are sent as response to an autoresponse or to another email that was sent from the Case) you can check if this EmailMessage attribute : ReplyToEmailMessageId is null or not (on top of the incoming == true).

If it's null it's the email that created the case, if it's not, it's a reply, so you can consider it's an update.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if customer replies from email it should be change status.Can you please provide me some snippet.

Comment: yes can you try this out : in your for loop, add a third criteria in your IF statement, to check if the EmailMessage attribute ReplyToEmailMessageId is not null.

for (EmailMessage email : Trigger.new) {
        if (email.Incoming && email.ParentId != null && email.ReplyToEmailMessageId != null) {
            caseIds.add(email.ParentId);
        }
    }